# Zero Based Counting

Tags: javascript

> For a variety of historical reasons, programming languages almost always count
>   things in a zero-based fashion, meaning starting with 0 instead of 1.

Why is it like this? Why not 1? I am currently reading "You don't know JS" and I found this.

Comment: http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html

Comment: The book is being a bit misleading there. They aren’t just historical reasons; they’re *good* reasons.

Comment: Well, the answer is in your question: "For a variety of historical reasons" :)

Answer (score 0):

counting from zero is slightly more efficient than starting at 1.

Let’s explore a simple mathematical equation to understand why:

If we count from zero, every value in the array of length N, can be represented by the following equation where i represents the numerical position of each value:

0 ≤ i < N

REf: https://skillcrush.com/2013/01/17/why-programmers-start-counting-at-zero/

Answer (score 0):

You often use references in computer programming, like "resource A is located in memory at position X". This resource might as well be a simple text, just for example. Let's say the text is "Text". For simplicity, let's say the memory consists of 1 byte slots, so your text is a 4 byte long resource.

So, how are you referencing the single letters in this text resource? Quite simple, you take your reference pointing to the resource location (which would be the first byte of your resource) and add 1, 2 or 3 to it, to get the rest of the text.

```
memory(resourceStart + 0) = 'T'
memory(resourceStart + 1) = 'e'
memory(resourceStart + 2) = 'x'
memory(resourceStart + 3) = 't'
```

In C, for example, there is a short notation for this:

```
resourceStart[0] = 'T'
resourceStart[1] = 'e'
resourceStart[2] = 'x'
resourceStart[3] = 't'
```

Since most of the references of memory objects refer to the first byte of the resource, this zero-based counting is rather practical.